# Magento2: How to return grouped products in search?

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, search, grouped-products

How does Magento handle Grouped Products in search? For example, if a site has products 1, 2, 3 inside of grouped product 4, when searching for a search term that is contained it product 3's description, would product 4 be returned by the search? If not, is there a way to alter this behavior?